# Retrieving image from database in php code that is put inside print

Tags: php

i'm sure there is syntax error here but i couldn't find exactly what it is:

```
Print"  <img STYLE='border: thin solid grey;
                    left:00px;top:00px;'
                    src="<?php echo $info['Spec_Photo'];?>" 
                    alt='idimage' width='110' height='110'>";
```

the image is already saved in the database

Answer (score 1):

```
print("<img STYLE='border: thin solid grey;
    left:00px;top:00px;'
    src=\"". $info['Spec_Photo'] . "\" 
    alt='idimage' width='110' height='110'>");
```

Comment: now there is no error but the image doesn't displayed, instead of that the word "idimage" is getting displayed in the image's place

Comment: Does the generated image src point to a valid image (can you open it in your browser)?

Comment: @user3419062 then its using the image `alt` tag, `var_dump($info['Spec_Photo']);` to see what you have in there

Comment: it doesn't display an image how can you where it points? only displaying the word idimage

Comment: where should i put this var_dump($info['Spec_Photo']); ??

Comment: @user3419062 You can use the "View Source" functionality in your browser or the debugging tool of your choice (Firebug, Chrome Developer, etc) to see the final generated HTML for the img tag. The "src" attribute needs to point to a valid URL for an image to load properly.

Comment: pasting  var_dump($info['Spec_Photo']);  gave me this result: **string(0) "" string(29) "il_340x270.570372508_20s3.jpg" string(0) ""** what does it mean?

Comment: You'll need to add a URL or path relative to the current page where that file can be located and loaded by the browser. For instance, if you have an absolute URL where that image is hosted (say `http://www.myimagehost.com/images/`) then you need to add this in front of the image filename in the above code (`src=\"http://www.myimagehost.com/images/". $info['Spec_Photo'] . "\"`).

Comment: looks like its running the `var_dump` twice,  are you in a loop? The second time it contained a `.jpg` name, so that's good, proably you're missing the path to the images folder you should try `src=\"/path/to/your/images/". $info['Spec_Photo'] . "\" `

Comment: what do you mean that i have url? it's just uploaded in phpmyadmin so what can the absolute url be like?

Comment: yes it's in  a loop. it contained .jpg but it's displayed nothing. the path starts from the file inside htdocs, right? my images folder are inside a folder called 'sw' that is inside htdocs folder, so the path will be like: sw/images/".$info['Spec_Photo'].". but there is somethind else, i don't see the photos i uploaded in the images folder

Comment: try `src=\"/sw/images/". $info['Spec_Photo'] . "\"`

Comment: still nothing is displayed, the folder itself doesn't have any image

Comment: @user3419062 and what would you like me to do about that? upload it for you?

Comment: I uploaded it but it's not in the file. that's what i meant

Answer (score -2):

did you save the image with the extension in the database? image.jpg? if not you need to add the extension .jpg like this:

```
                 Print"  <img STYLE='border: thin solid grey;
                 left:00px;top:00px;'
                 src="<?php echo $info['Spec_Photo'];?>.jpg" 
                 alt='idimage' width='110' height='110'>";
```

Comment: i didnt check the code for syntax errors, i was just making sure the image is actually saved in the db as a path to an images folder and if the extension is also saved in the db it would be like this:

Comment: how can i save it as a path, it's just a variable of type blob

Comment: you don't save an image in the database instead you save the image name and retrieve the image from images folder, let's say your image is image1.jpg in folder images, in your Table you have img_src you add image1 now to see this image:<img src='images/$row['img_src'].jpg'/> im not checking my code for syntax errors but this is the concept to save and retrieve images

Comment: but this function is supposed to be for adding specialists to the system, i don't want to force the user to add that image to the images folder, just uploading it in the website is enough

Comment: your question title is Retrieving image from database in php code that is put inside print, this is the best way to retrieve an image from a website doesnt matter if you add it or uploaded by the user, hope you find a better solution.